# Finding a Correlation between Bernoulli Variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation, bernoulli-numbers

Let X and Y be Bernoulli random variables. We don't assume independence or identical distribution, but we do assume that all 4 of the following probabilities are nonzero.

Let a := P[X = 1, Y = 1], b := P[X = 1, Y = 0], c := P[X = 0, Y = 1],
and d := P[X = 0, Y = 0].

How do I obtain a formula for a correlation between random variables X and Y?

Answer (score 11):

Stefan Hansen's hint is a good one. Here is the complete derivation:
$${\rm E}[X]=a+b=p$$
$${\rm E}[Y]=a+c=q$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(X) & ={\rm E}[(X - {\rm E}[X])^2] \\
& = {\rm E}[(X - p)^2] \\
&= p(1-p)^2 + (1-p)(-p)^2 \\
& = p (1-2p+p^2) + p^2 - p^3 \\
& = p - 2p^2 + p^3+p^2-p^3 \\
& = p - p^2 \\
& = p(1-p) 
\end{align}
$$\sigma{_X}  =\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)} = \sqrt{p(1-p)} = \sqrt{(a+b)(1-(a+b))}$$
$$\sigma{_Y}  =\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(Y)} = \sqrt{q(1-q)} = \sqrt{(a+c)(1-(a+c))}$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y) &= \rm{E}[XY] - \rm{E}[X]\rm{E}[Y] \\
&=a - pq \\
&=a - (a+b)(a+c) \\
\end{align}
Finally, by substitution into the equation for $\rho_{XY}$:
\begin{align}
\rho_{XY}&=\frac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}} \\
&=\frac{a - (a+b)(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(1-(a+b))}\sqrt{(a+c)(1-(a+c))}} \\
&=\frac{a - (a+b)(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(1-(a+b))(a+c)(1-(a+c))}}
\end{align}

Comment: Note that the numerator simplifies to the determinant ad-bc.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: The correlation is defined in terms of $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$, $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ which can be computed if we know the following quantities
$$
{\rm E}[X],{\rm E}[X^2],{\rm E}[Y],{\rm E}[Y^2],{\rm E}[XY].
$$
These should be straightforward to find. For instance, 
$$
{\rm E}[X^2]={\rm E}[X]=P(X=1)=a+b.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you're talking about the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient).  It's defined in terms of the covariance and the standard deviations.  These in turn are defined in terms of
expected values, which are defined in terms of probabilities.  For example, 
$E[X] = 1 \cdot P(X=1) + 0 \cdot P(X=0) = a + b$.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer may be generalized to cover the case where rho is a user selected value and the values $E(x)=E(y)=\mu$ and $V(x)=V(y)=\sigma^2$ are equal and known. In this case:

$E(x)=a+b=E(y)=a+c=\mu$, therefore $b=c$ and $(a+b)*(a+c)=\mu^2$  (note $\mu<1$)

The $a,b,c$,and $d$ values are joint probability values such that:

$a+b+c+d=1$ by definition. So that $d= 1-(a+b+c)$

And by using the definition of the variance for Bernoulli random variables, by setting $V(x)=V(y)=\sigma^2$ the equation below follows:

$V(x)=(a+b)\cdot[1-(a+b)]=V(y)=(a+c)*[1-(a+c)]=\sigma^2=(\mu^2)\cdot(1-\mu)^2$

Then, using the originally derived equations for rho(xy)and Cov(x,y) above, it is possible to define rho in terms of the values of just a and mu, such that:

$\rho= \frac{a - \mu^2}{\mu(1-\mu)}$

Then solving for a we see that all values are known from rho, mu and sigma:

$$a= \mu^2 + [\rho(\mu(1-\mu))]\\
b= \mu - a\\
c= b\\
d= 1-(a+b+c)$$

Two correlated Bernoulli random variables can be simulated by first defining a discrete random variable $Z$ with four values: $3,2,1,0$ with the respective probabilities of $a,b,c,d$ corresponding to the four joint probability states. Then,

$x=1$ when $Z=3$ or $2$, $x=0$ otherwise
$y=1$ when $Z=3$ or $1$, $y=0$ otherwise

A Monte Carlo simulation with an Excel add-in then demonstrates that the $x$ and $y$ variables are correlated as specified by rho given the known values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$. The Excel CORREL function for $5000$ samples in a Monte Carlo simulation verifies this. Also, as a cross check when $\rho=0$ you may quickly show that the values of $a,b,c$, and $d$ are properly computed for the case where $x$ and $y$ are independent random variables.

Thanks to all of the original contributors for the work that prompted the above derivation.

Comment: Could you please format this in mathjax?  It would be taken a lot more seriously by a lot of users, if you did.

Comment: Believe that the webmaster for Stack Exchange did that in the last "edit" submitted.  I am not a MathJax user. One clarification to the original write-up: in the second sentence it is the expected values of x and y that are set equal, as are the variances of x and y. As originally worded that could be confused.