# Estimate relationship between two Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, parameter-estimation

- $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli random variables
- $X$ and $Y$ are not independent
- $x_{t} = P(X_t = 1)$ and $y_{t} = P(X_t = 1)$ for time $t$.
- Is it possible to estimate $P(Y = 1 | X = 1)$ from many pairs of $x_{t}$ and $y_{t}$?

I tried:

$$\frac{\sum_{t}y_{t}x_{t}}{\sum_{t}x_{t}}$$

But this formula doesn't make sense because that means $P(X = 1|X = 1)$ is

$$\frac{\sum_{t}x_{t}x_{t}}{\sum_{t}x_{t}}$$

which is not necessarily 1.

Comment: seems related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610443/finding-a-correlation-between-bernoulli-variables

Comment: Can't do much in this case. Have to assume that the two probability variables are independent at each point of time.

Comment: How do you get $x_t$ and $y_t$? Are they given? Are $\{(X_t,Y_t)\}$ i.i.d?

Comment: Something here doesn't make too much sense; what is $(X_t,Y_t)$?  It seems like you want $(X_t,Y_t)_{t}$ to be independent samples of $(X,Y)$, but their parameters seem to be $(x_t,y_t)$, which further seem to be changing.

Answer (score 1):

Throw away the data where $x_t \neq 1$. Then compute the proportion of the remaining data where $y_t = 1$.