# Definition of correlation between events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, correlation

I often hear people talk about correlation between events, e.g. event A and event B are positively correlated.

However, unlike correlation between random variables (i.e. $\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}$ ), I can't seem to find a numerical definition of correlation **between events**.

In [this book](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/02%3A_Probability_Spaces/2.04%3A_Conditional_Probability#:%7E:text=Intuitively%2C%20if%20A%20and%20B,other%20event%20is%20less%20likely.), it is mentioned that

1. $\mathbb{P}(∣)$ > $\mathbb{P}()$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(∣)$ > $\mathbb{P}()$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(∩) > \mathbb{P}()\mathbb{P}()$. In this case,  and  are positively correlated.
2. $\mathbb{P}(∣) < \mathbb{P}()$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(∣) < \mathbb{P}()$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(∩) < \mathbb{P}()\mathbb{P}()$. In this case,  and  are negatively correlated.
3. $\mathbb{P}(∣) = \mathbb{P}()$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(∣) = \mathbb{P}()$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(∩) = \mathbb{P}()\mathbb{P}()$. In this case,  and  are uncorrelated or independent.

However, there is still no numerical definition of correlation between events.

**What is the numerical formula definition of correlation between events? Is it a number between -1 and 1?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a Correlation between Bernoulli Variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610443/finding-a-correlation-between-bernoulli-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the book gives a definition of correlation between two events that amounts to saying that two events are correlated if they are not independent.

The quantity $\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$ is the [Pearson Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) and serves as a numerical measure of *linear* correlation between two random variables. There are other kinds of [correlation coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient) that might be useful in other applications, though I am not as familiar.

I suppose if you wanted a numerical measure of the linear correlation between two events, $A,B$, you could consider the pearson correlation coefficient of the r.v. indicators of these events, $I_A$ and $I_B$. Using $\text{Cov}(I_A,I_B) = \text{E}[I_AI_B] - \text{E}[I_A][I_B]$ and the fact that $\text{E}[I_A] = \mathbb{P}(A)$, $\text{E}[I_B]= \mathbb{P}(B)$,  and $\text{E}[I_AI_B] = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$ one arrives at $\text{Cov}(I_A,I_B) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) - \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$. Using $\sigma_{I_A}^2 = \mathbb{P}(A)(1-\mathbb{P}(A))$ and a similar formula for $\sigma_{I_B}^2$, you can calculate the pearson correlation coefficient.

Comment: Makes sense. We could define the correlation between two events as the Pearson correlation between their indicators.

Comment: By the way, I believe $E[I_A I_B] = \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$, so there is a typo in your response.

Comment: Yes you are right, good catch.